SwiftUI ScrollView does not scroll to the bottom
I'm building a chat app. When the user changes the text in the input field, I want to move the chat messages up, so I scroll it to the bottom. Most of the time, it works, but sometimes the bottom of the scroll view is covered a little bit.
Here is the code:
GeometryReader { geoProxy in
    ScrollViewReader { scrollProxy in
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: .zero) {
                Spacer(minLength: 0)

                VStack(spacing: .atlasSpaceLarge) {
                    ForEach(messages) { message in
                        messageView(for: message)
                            .id(message.id)
                    }
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: geoProxy.size.height) { _ in
                if let message = messages.last {
                    withAnimation {
                        scrollProxy.scrollTo(message.id, anchor: .bottom)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Here are the screenshots.


Thank you!

It did scroll to the bottom but not totally bottom. I'm not sure why.

Is it same behaviour if you change scrollProxy.scrollTo(message.id, anchor: .bottom) to scrollProxy.scrollTo(0, anchor: .bottom) ? Thats what I'm doing in a large textfield showing some log-files
